# Given checkboxes, how do I delete the corresponding database row?

Tags: mysql, html, perl, datatable

I am trying to delete MySQL table rows from a Web page using Perl. I want to iterate over checkboxes and if one is checked, that row from the database will be deleted. I have made the value of the checkbox the auto incrementing key value. Here is a piece of my code, so you can get an idea of where I am at, table-wise:

```
while (@data = $STH1->fetchrow_array()) {
    print "<tr>";
    print " <td>$data[2]</td>";
    print " <td>$data[3]</td>";
    print " <td>$data[7]</td>";
    print " <td>$data[6]</td>";
    print " <td>$data[4]</td>";
    print " <td>$data[5]</td>";
    print " <td>$data[1]</td>";
    print "<td>";
    print '<form><center>';
    print checkbox(
        -name     => 'delete',
        -value    => 'data[0]',
        -selected => 0,
        -label    => 'delete'
    );
    print '<center></form>';
    print "</td>";
    print "</tr>";
}
```

I just do not understand how I can make it delete a row if a checkbox is checked.

Comment: `print "<td>$_</td>" for @data[2,3,7,6,4,5,1];` will replace your repetitive print statements.

Comment: was going to suggest the same thing. print is a list function and that is a good thing(tm). ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe your call to checkbox needs to be tweaked a bit:

```
print checkbox(
    -name => 'delete',
    # -value => 'data[0]'
    # should be
    -value => $data[0],
    # do you need this ?
    # -selected => 0,
    -label => 'delete'
);
```

then in your cgi or object:

```
my @ids_to_delete = $q->param( 'delete' );
```

will get you the rows to delete by id and then you just build & run your delete statement.

Comment: ok well i kind of am following what you are saying but i dont know how to set up my delete statement

Comment: pseudo code: "delete from <table> where id in <list>" where <list> is @ids_to_delete. check out the sql 'in' operator. also, remember to untaint the values in the list before interpolating them into a sql statement. make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CGI`, create a `form` with all checkboxes within it.

Then by another script, again `CGI`, read submitted form values and based on selected checkboxes execute SQL `delete` command to remove requested rows from table.

Be sure you use unique `id` column as an identificator for your form checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You want to POST the data to a second perl script.
In the second perl script you pick up the row as a query paramter.
You have the id of the row you want to delete.
Then call a deleteRow function with that id which has the SQL in it.

I am using http://template-toolkit.org/ right now to do basically what you have described.

Answer (score 0):

Well your form in inside your loop so your going to have a different form for each checkbox.

If you want to support multiple deletes, you'll have to move your form open and close tags outside the loop.

Then you add an hidden input inside your loop.  Use "id" for the name of the hidden and "delete" for the checkbox.

I'm not sure about cgi but you should and get the form back as two dimensional array of two fields.  Loop through that collect.  If the checkbox is present and checked (sometimes you don't get back an unchecked checkbox) look for the id.  Then add the id to a list and continue looping.

Then create your delete statement from the list.  Check to see the number of rows deleted and return that message to your user.

Hope that helps...

Comment: also, it looks like your setting the value of the checkbox to the id.  I don't think that works.  the value for checkboxes is "checked' or null.